# MongoDB Atlas Scanned Objects / Returned in fixed sized aggregation results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm getting alerts of "Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000" on an aggregation query that I perform.

First, the target is to have an aggregation of 7 days, each day with a count of unique `userId` values.
So in this case, the result of the aggregation would be 7 documents, where each document id is the relevant date, and a field of `count` that indicates how many unique `userId` values there are for this day.

I perform the following aggregation **for example**:

```
[
  { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: {"$date": 1613001600000} } }},
  {
    $bucket: {
      boundaries: [
        {
          "$date": 1613001600000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613088000000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613174400000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613260800000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613347200000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613433600000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613520000000
        },
        {
          "$date": 1613606400000
        }
      ],
      groupBy: "$timestamp",
      output: { users: { $addToSet: "$userId" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: { $size: "$users" },
    }
  }
]
```

The `explain()` of this aggregation is:

```
"queryPlanner": {
  "plannerVersion": 1,
  "namespace": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6.device_events",
  "indexFilterSet": false,
  "parsedQuery": {
    "timestamp": {
      "$gte": ISODate("2021-02-11T00:00:00Z")
    }
  },
  "queryHash": "3F0BEC12",
  "planCacheKey": "3F0BEC12",
  "winningPlan": {
    "stage": "COLLSCAN",
    "filter": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2021-02-11T00:00:00Z")
      }
    },
    "direction": "forward"
  },
  "rejectedPlans": []
},
"executionStats": {
  "executionSuccess": true,
  "nReturned": 376966,
  "executionTimeMillis": 381,
  "totalKeysExamined": 0,
  "totalDocsExamined": 441545,
  "executionStages": {
    "stage": "COLLSCAN",
    "filter": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2021-02-11T00:00:00Z")
      }
    },
    "nReturned": 376966,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
    "works": 441547,
    "advanced": 376966,
    "needTime": 64580,
    "needYield": 0,
    "saveState": 3478,
    "restoreState": 3478,
    "isEOF": 1,
    "direction": "forward",
    "docsExamined": 441545
  }
}
```

Somehow the `explain()` shows a different value for `nReturned` than the profiler output for the exact same aggregation.
The profiler output shows `nReturned` of 7 which is expected.

So as I see it, I will always get this alert since the number of documents in 7 days is `X > 1007`, and the number of **returned** documents will always be 7.

Am I missing anything? is this a bad solution for getting the results I need?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: https://p-mongo.github.io/mongodb-faq/query/indexing-query-optimization/#query-plan

Comment: @D.SM added the `explain()` details thanks! although I think I am missing something much more fundamental. since the aggregation always returns 7 documents, so the ratio will always be bad (also the profiler shows a different value than the `executionStats`)

Comment: The execution is basically what I would expect, with the exception that I expected also to see the bucket stage in there somehow but maybe it isn't reported.

Comment: Exactly, but my question is that: the collection has 300K of documents, and the bucket will return exactly 7 documents (one for each day) . Is there any other way to achieve this aggregation? Because the ratio will always be above 1000

Comment: If you need all of the documents in the collection, a collection scan will naturally be the best solution. You haven't linked to either documentation for this warning or where you got it from but I would focus on 1) whether the warning is in fact operating as described, 2) whether the query analyzer should be smarter, and 3) reporting all that to MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses by the way! https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/alert-resolutions/query-targeting/ this is the alert I'm getting